# Example: Operator with empty spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

I tried Google and a few books but couldn't find a suitable example. Does anyone know an example of an (unbounded closed) Operator BETWEEN HILBERTSPACES(!), that has empty spectrum?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can someone give me a hint as why to close this as off-topic? Thanks! ;)

Comment: Have a look into excercise X.1.10 of conway's functional analysis.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A closed densely-defined linear operator on a Hilbert space can have empty spectrum. For example, let $H=L^{2}[0,1]$ and let $A=\frac{d}{dx}$ on the domain consisting of absolutely continuous $f \in L^{2}$ for which $f(0)=0$ and $f' \in L^{2}$. To show that $A$ has no spectrum, it is enough to prove that the resolvent $R(\lambda)=(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$ exists everywhere. To do this, given $g\in L^{2}$, solve
$$
                     f'-\lambda f = g, \;\;\; f(0)=0.
$$
The unique solution is trivially obtained:
$$
                      \frac{d}{dx}(e^{-\lambda x}f)=e^{-\lambda x}g \\
                    f(x)=e^{\lambda x}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-\lambda t}g(t)dt
$$
It is is easy to verify that $f$ is the correct solution. So $A$ has empty spectrum because its resolvent exists everywhere:
$$
              R(\lambda)g = (A-\lambda I)^{-1}g = \int_{0}^{x}e^{\lambda(x-t)}g(t)dt.
$$

Comment: Nice example. But how do you define $f(0)=0$ on $L^2[0,1]$? It is $\mu(\{0\})=0$.

Comment: @KennyH : $L^2$ consists of equivalence classes $[f]$ of functions that are equal a.e.. The domain of $A$ consists of all $[f]$ for which there exists an absolutely continuous $g \in [f]$ for which $g(0)=0$. Then $A[f]=[g']$. That's the technical definition. The domain can also be defined by the set of equivalence classes $\{ [\int_{0}^{x}h(t)dt] : h \in L^{2}\}$. NOTE: The domain of $A$ is not all of $L^{2}$.