# Operator with a single point as spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Give an example of a bounded operator acting on a Hilbert space, whose spectrum consists of a single point. I can only think of the $0$ operator an a multiple of the identity, is there any other simple but non-trivial example? Thanks

Comment: That's a strange way of stating the problem, since the $0$ operator *is* a multiple of the identity.

Comment: What are you assuming about the space that you are working with?

Comment: Just that it is a Hilbert space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

$$
M=\begin{pmatrix}
a&1\\0&a
\end{pmatrix}
$$

has the only eigenvalue $a$.  For an $n\times n$  matrix you can find more examples using different Jordan blocks with the same diagonal elements.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ be an operator on an Hilbert $H$ space such that $A$ [has empty spectrum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1344287/example-operator-with-empty-spectrum). Define $$\begin{array}{rccc}A^\star\colon&H\oplus\mathbb{C}&\longrightarrow&H\oplus\mathbb{C}\\&(v,z)&\mapsto&\bigl(A(v),0\bigr).\end{array}$$Then the spectrum of $A^\star$ is $\{0\}$, but $A^\star$ is not a multiple of the identity.

Comment: Why is $A^\star$ bounded?

Comment: *If* $A$ is bounded, then $A^\star $ is bounded too.

Comment: Of course, but only an unbounded operator can have empty spectrum and the OP requested a bounded one...

Comment: @haemi Sure. My mistake. But now I remember why I didn't care for that originally. The [first version](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2350248/revisions) of the question didn't mention that.

Comment: Oh alright. Perhaps it would be convenient if MSE marked an answer in some way if the question's most recent edit happens after the answer's...